# Getting file name and changing a button to that name

Tags: c#, forms, filenames

Im just getting into C# forms and im wondering how to change a button text to the name of a file you are opening i have it somewhat working but when i open the file the buttons text changes to the path of that file i just want the files name

```
OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
op.Title = "open";
op.Filter = "Text Document(*.txt)|*.txt|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
 if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      richTextBox1.LoadFile(op.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
      button1.Text = op.FileName;
      this.Text = op.FileName;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to check out the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.  Remember to reference `System.IO`

```
OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
op.Title = "open";
op.Filter = "Text Document(*.txt)|*.txt|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
 if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      richTextBox1.LoadFile(op.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
      button1.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(op.FileName);  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Path.GetFileName(op.FileName);
```

Comment: A good explanation of what is causing the OP's problem, and how to solve it is needed here. Nobody learns when they are spoon-fed.